# Installation Errors + File Association Errors Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, installation

I uninstalled python 2.7.2 today as i have had both python 2 and 3 on my computer when it is only python 3 i use. After I uninstalled it all of my python files associated with notepad and it would not allow me to change it to python again - No Error Message but just wont register the change. I tried rebooting but that did not work so i decided to reinstall python 3.4 again as well, i did this and now i found out that whilst i can open the python file, i cannot open the pythonw file and therefore am unable to open the idle window to do anything. I have rebooted the system since then several times, tried another install but nothing happens and i am unable to use python at the moment.
A fix to both problems would be greatly appreciated but i am more worried about python not being able to be opened.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be fixed by doing a system restore to a point before, then installing again